# init not called on custom a class swift

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

```
class Facts {
    var networkOperaton = NetworkOperation(url: "http://fact.tayfunturanligil.com")
    var factsArray : [String] = []
    init () {
        self.networkOperaton.downloadJSONFromURL({
            (a:[String]) -> [String] in
            println(a)
            self.factsArray = a
            return a
        })
    }
}
```

When I want to create an instance of Facts in my ViewController using `var facts = Facts()`, `factsArray` stays as an empty array. But it should be getting an array from `downloadJSONFromURL` function. Why this is happening? Even my `println(a)` is not called.

I tested `downloadJSONFromURL` function in a playground and it works. Also, `networkOperation` uses `NSURLSession`, could this be an issue?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I want my factsArray to be assigned an array but it does not. I think my entire init function is not being called because println(a) is never called. Why this might be happening?

Comment: Put print test just after init, not in the part below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `init()` method is actually called. Try out this code:

```
class Facts {
   var factsArray : [String] = []
   init () {
       println("Init called")
       factsArray = ["Hello", "World", "Bye", "World"]
   }
}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var facts = Facts()
    println(facts.factsArray)
}
```

The problem with your code would be that network operation would be running in asynchronous mode. Instead of making network request in init method you can define another method in function which can then return status of request in completion block.

```
func updateArrayFromNetwork(completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
    var networkOperaton = NetworkOperation(url: "http://fact.tayfunturanligil.com")
    self.networkOperaton.downloadJSONFromURL({
        (a:[String]) -> [String] in
        println(a)
        self.factsArray = a
        completion(true)
    })
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var facts = Facts()
    println(facts.factsArray)

    facts.updateArrayFromNetwork { (completed: Bool) -> () in
        if completed {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats solved the problem. but a couple new problems appeared. 1) the app is incredibly slow now( it is fast if I use NSData insted of NSURLSeesion. 2) I have a println("network init done") statement in my networkOperation init() but I see network init done statement twice. 3) dont I need to use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() function somewere. Again thanks for the help

Comment: `NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL, options: NSDataReadingOptions, error: NSErrorPointer)` is generally meant to load data from local url (Documents folder or any other file from local storage. You must use NSURLSession's sendAsynchronousRequest: [link][1]

[1]:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:

Answer (score 0):

`init()` is called but `downloadJSONFromURL()` is an asynchronous method.
That means `init()` returns immediately the `Facts` instance after calling `downloadJSONFromURL()` without waiting for completion.